# Evaluating a hard integral related to the two-fluid model

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, physics

The following definite integral describing the density of the normal part of a superfluid equals to
$$
\int_0^\infty dx\, x^4\, \frac{e^{x^2+a}}{\left(e^{x^2+a}-1\right)^2} = \frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{8}Li_{3/2}(e^{-a})\quad , \qquad a>0\, .
$$
However, if one types the above expression into *Mathematica*

```
Integrate[ x^4 Exp[x^2+a]/(Exp[x^2 + a] - 1)^2, {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

then it simply returns the input.

Why is that and how can one solve these kind of problems?

I've been thinking for quite a while now, that the above integral does not have a closed form solution because *Mathematica* couldn't solve it.

Comment: The RHS of the formula you asked for is not a closed-form expression. In fact,the integral under consideration is expressed in the terms of another integral..Hope you understand Mathematica is not a table of integrals.

Comment: True, thank you for making that point. However, there are expressions where Mathematica does give special functions as results to integrals similar as above. Is there a way, to make Mathematica express these kind of integrals in terms of special functions?

Comment: The question arises: what for?  Isn't it art for art's sake?

Comment: Well, it is the accepted way of writing those integrals in the literature and if one sees special functions one immediately knows that the integral at hand corresponds to some special functions. Additionally, one can apply all the current knowledge that we have about the properties of the special functions to the integral, once we know that this integral corresponds to a special function.

Comment: Did you look in Gradstein&Ruezhik to this end (They give references to the formulas.)? Good luck!

Comment: No I didn't. Thank you for the reference, didn't know it till now.
(So there is no way to tell Mathematica to express non solvable integrals in terms of special functions?)

Comment: @mr.curious You could define your own numerical function depending on `a `.

Comment: I guess you intended `PolyLog` not just `LogIntegral`, didn't you?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes you are right! Li is in Mathematica PolyLog

Comment: @mr.curious Why you show this question without link to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/575721/closed-form-solution-to-normal-fluid-density-integral-in-the-two-fluid-model/575740?noredirect=1#comment1298320_575740 ? :)

Comment: @Alex Trounev I'm sorry, I am not very familiar with stack exchange so it did not come across my mind. Thank you for pointing this out. I'll try to keep it in mind in the future. Having said that, I also asked initially in the math section as I was not sure which one is most suited. Here is the link:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804196/closed-form-solution-of-a-definite-integral-of-an-exponential-function

Comment: @mr.curious It will be reasonable if you add some details regarding the physical background of the integral. Does it  describe plasma or simply fluid dynamics? Two-fluid Euler-Maxwell system or certain reduced model?

Comment: @Artes Well, it says it in the title. The integral is used for calculating the density of the normal part of a superfluid, so here we are in ultra cold physics context. This is based on the two fluid model by Landau and Tisza. The exponent is a high momentum approximation to the full spectrum that I made. Feel free to ask for more detail :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can see that the integrand is a derivative with respect to $a$ (the integral is absolutely convergent and continuously differentiable so integration and differentiation is commutative) of a bit simpler function which can be integrated, i.e we can see that $$\frac{d}{da}\; \frac{x^k}{\exp(x^2+a)-1}=-\frac{x^k \exp(x^2+a)}{(\exp(x^2+a)-1)^2}$$
and now **we can evaluate even a more general integral** of the form
$$
\int_0^\infty dx\,  \frac{x^k e^{x^2+a}}{\left(e^{x^2+a}-1\right)^2} 
$$

```
int[k_,a_] = Integrate[ -x^k/(Exp[x^2 + a] - 1), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
                        Assumptions -> a > 0 && k > 0]
```

> ```
> -(Gamma[(1 + k)/2] PolyLog[(1 + k)/2, E^(-a)])/2
> ```

i.e. **the more general integral** takes  form:

```
D[ int[k,a], a]
```

> ```
>  (Gamma[(1 + k)/2] PolyLog[-1 + (1 + k)/2, E^(-a)])/2
> ```

so it is in **case of the original question**

```
 % /. k -> 4 // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

In any case one can also compare the integral with its numerical counterpart, e.g.

```
nint[k_, a_]:= NIntegrate[ x^k Exp[x^2 + a]/(Exp[x^2 + a] - 1)^2,{x, 0, Infinity}]

 Plot[{3/8 Sqrt[Pi] PolyLog[3/2, Exp[-a]], nint[4,a]}, {a, 0, 3},
   PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Dashing[{0.02, 0.05}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case, Mathematica did not evaluate the first line of yours " (-3 Sqrt[Pi] PolyLog[5/2, E^(-a)]) " either. So I quit kernel and now it evaluates your first line as well as the integral in my question directly without the intermediary step. Thanks!

Comment: -1. `Integrate[ %, a]` produces an antiderivative up to a constant. In order to complete your derivation, you need to determine that constant and this is not simple..

Comment: @user64494 I fixed that before you pointed it out, as can be seen from the substatial part of the edit and so you should upvote it rather than downvote.

Comment: Your comparison is not any proof. Hope you understand it: think of `10^-1000`.

Comment: I don't play with a mathematical proof and it  need not any of that, since the system doesn't guffs up on the basic level. I've  just mentioned that the integral is correct before.

Comment: Hint: `Limit[(3 Sqrt[Pi] PolyLog[7/2, E^(-a)])/8, a -> Infinity]` produces `0`. Hope the rest is cleatr to you.

Comment: @Artes Very tricky solution ! Don't worry about several comments...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks!  Some cases are incurable, simply  terminal.

Comment: It is clever, yes.

Comment: @Artes Did you seen my answer on https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/575721/closed-form-solution-to-normal-fluid-density-integral-in-the-two-fluid-model/575740?noredirect=1#comment1298320_575740 ? :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks for the link, I 've just taken a look at that. I haven't got an acount there even though I'm a physicist.

Comment: @Artes Ok! I gave this answer yesterday on Physics using Mathematica and now I see  this answer on Mathematica with using physics. :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev Your calculation has the same deficiency that Artes' one: you don't take into account an integration constant.

Comment: @user64494 What are you talking  about?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Coincidentally, I first learned this technique in a review session for a physics class I was taking.

Comment: @user64494 Definite integrals don't have integration constants (they cancel out).